# Obtener el Elemento actual desde angularjs, (como el this en javascript)

Tags: angularjs

necesito obtener el elemento actual, para poder manipular los elementos que lo rodean, pero no se si eso se pueda con angularjs, asi como en jQuery que podemos manipular el DOM. 
Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Ya probaste con angular.element("elemento") ??

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos un ejemplo en jquery? Asi quizas podamos mostrarte como se hace en angular.

Comment: Hola @CamiloVasquez, este seria un ejemplo en jQuery                                       mira $(obj).parent().parent().css("background", 'red'').prevAll().css("background", 'red');
        $(obj).parent().parent().nextAll().css("background", 'blue');

Comment: @NancyZj el angular.element funciona igual que el $ de jQuery es decir que podrías hacer algo como angular.element(obj).parent().parent().nextAll().css("background", 'blue');

Comment: @CamiloVasquez, disculpa pero ahí object, es el this y angular no se cual seria el this, intente usar el $event, pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo he capturado el this en angular de la siguiente forma:

```
<button ng-click="capturar($event)">capturar</button>

$scope.capturar = function($event){
    angular.element($event.toElement).parent();
}
```

`angular.element` = funciona como el `$` de `jQuery`

`$event.toElement` = funciona como el `this`

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Gracias, si me devuelve el objeto :)

Comment: Si la respuesta sirvió para tu solución te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que los futuros desarrolladores sepan que fue una solución correcta al problema y lo puedan implementar. Me alegra que te sirviera, te invito a que te hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y bienvenida a esta grandiosa comunidad !